# python : Iterate through the list values and get the key in json

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I have the below json:

```
{
    "repo_url":"git@github.plugin.git",
    "latest_commit":"bfe7bxxxx",
    "old_commit":"a4ccbyyy",
    "region": {
                    "A":["us-south","us-east"],
                    "B":["au-syd","germany"]
            }
 }
```

I need to get the key value `A` if I provide `us-east` or `us-south` as input. Similarly I need to get `B` if I provide `au-syd` or `germany` as input. How do I loop through this json construct.

I have tried below code as a starting point

```
 output_json = json.load(open(file))
            print output_json["region"]

            for majorkey, subdict in output_json["region"]:
                print subdict
```

But that throws below error

```
for majorkey, subdict in output_json["region"]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: This `output_json["region"]` is not correct you need either `output_json["region"].items()` or `output_json["region"].iteritems()` for python 3 and python 2 respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `iteritems` instead of just iterating over dict

```
In [3]: for k, v in output_json['region'].iteritems():
   ...:     if 'us-south' in v:
   ...:         print(v.index('us-south'))
   ...:         print(k)
   ...:         
0
A
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments. This is what you may want.

> For python3.*

```
for majorkey, subdict in output_json['region'].items():
    print(subdict)
```

> For python2.*

```
for majorkey, subdict in output_json['region'].iteritems():
    print(subdict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in JavaScript, I hope it will work as per your expectation.

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "repo_url":"git@github.plugin.git",
    "latest_commit":"bfe7bxxxx",
    "old_commit":"a4ccbyyy",
    "region": {
                    "A":["us-south","us-east"],
                    "B":["au-syd","germany"]
            }
 };
 
 function input(val) {
   for (var i in Object.keys(jsonObj.region)) {
     for (var j in jsonObj.region[Object.keys(jsonObj.region)[i]]) {
       if (jsonObj.region[Object.keys(jsonObj.region)[i]][j] == val) {
         console.log(Object.keys(jsonObj.region)[i]);
       }
     }
   }
 }
 
 input("us-east");
```